# Can't replace text function in excel with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new working with this so have some patience please.

I'm tried with search and replace but in cells with function doesn't allow me.
I have an excel with too many functions, I  need erase the function REDONDEAR from every cell with a specific color. When I run the Macros it doesn't change the cells.

```
Sub foo()
Dim MR As Excel.Range
Dim rngCell As Excel.Range
Dim rngCount As Long

Set MR = Sheets("Hoja1").Range("A1:A827")

rngCount = 1

For Each rngCell In MR
    If rngCell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(226, 239, 218) Then
        rngCell.Select
        ActiveCell.Replace What:="REDONDEAR", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder _
    :=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
        rngCount = rngCount + 1
    End If
Next rngCell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time task, than I'd use a built-in tool (Ctrl+H).
But if not, well... As far as I can see, your code works fine. Three reasons why there is no result in your case:

1. Wrong range.
2. Wrong color.
3. Wrong function name.

Here's what I'd try. Change the range from a column to UsedRange to erase something from **every** cell with a specific color. Remove DisplayFormat, if the color of a cell is exactly what you are looking for, not the color you can see on a screen, which may be modified, for example, by conditional formatting. Make sure, you are looking for the correct color and word.

```
Sub Foo()
Dim Data As Range
Dim Cell As Range 
Dim SheetOfInterest as String
Dim WhatToErase as String
Dim ColorMark as Long
    SheetOfInterest = "Hoja1"
    WhatToErase = "REDONDEAR"
    ColorMark = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    Set Data = Sheets(SheetOfInterest).UsedRange 
    For Each Cell In Data
        If Cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = ColorMark Then
            Cell.Replace WhatToErase, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart
        End If
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

I left `DisplayFormat` in case if it was an intentional choice in the first place. But if it wasn't, then I'd recommend to try this approach: use the parameter SearchFormat to find cells with a specific color.

```
sub Baz()
Dim Data As Range
Dim SheetOfInterest as String
Dim WhatToErase as String
Dim ColorMark as Long
    SheetOfInterest = "Hoja1"
    WhatToErase = "REDONDEAR"
    ColorMark = RGB(226, 239, 218)
    Set Data = Sheets(SheetOfInterest).UsedRange
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
    Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = ColorMark
    Data.Replace WhatToErase, Replacement:="", _
        LookAt:=xlPart, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=True
    Application.FindFormat.Clear
End Sub
```

Comment: God bless you, thank u very much